# Detect biggest date overlap entity

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I want to find the maximum concurrent capacity of each instructor. If there is 1 day overlap between two course durations, then they are considered to be concurrent. I want the output as in column F.

Is there a way to achieve this output in Oracle SQL?

[image: instructor schedule]

Script to create the data-

```
create table instructor_schedule(instructor_id varchar2(5), course_id varchar2(5), course_start_dt date, course_end_dt date);

insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I1', 'C1', to_date('01-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('30-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I1', 'C2', to_date('25-DEC-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('15-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I1', 'C3', to_date('25-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('05-FEB-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I1', 'C4', to_date('26-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('26-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I1', 'C5', to_date('01-MAR-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('05-MAR-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));

insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I2', 'C1', to_date('20-AUG-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('22-AUG-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I2', 'C2', to_date('03-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('04-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I2', 'C3', to_date('02-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('02-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into instructor_schedule(instructor_id, course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt) values('I2', 'C4', to_date('01-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('05-SEP-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Comment: Why don't I1's C3 and C4 overlap with each other, as well as with C1?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have fixed the spreadsheet now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use scalar subquery with the condition on intersecting intervals:

```
select
  m.*
  , (
    select count(*)
    from instructor_schedule lkp
    where m.instructor_id = lkp.instructor_id
      and m.course_id != lkp.course_id
      and m.course_start_dt <= lkp.course_end_dt
      and lkp.course_start_dt <= m.course_end_dt
  ) as intersects
from instructor_schedule m
```

| INSTRUCTOR_ID | COURSE_ID | COURSE_START_DT | COURSE_END_DT | INTERSECTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | C1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 | 3 |
| I1 | C2 | 2021-12-25 | 2022-01-15 | 1 |
| I1 | C3 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-05 | 2 |
| I1 | C4 | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-26 | 2 |
| I1 | C5 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-05 | 0 |
| I2 | C1 | 2022-08-20 | 2022-08-22 | 0 |
| I2 | C2 | 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-04 | 1 |
| I2 | C3 | 2022-09-02 | 2022-09-02 | 1 |
| I2 | C4 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-05 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DW8K1H8Q)

**UPD**

Alternatively you may use a single table scan and [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-modeling-data-warehouses.html#GUID-CC847DA6-8838-412B-B984-AF75EA0FFAC8) clause to perform calculations over multiple rows. `cv` below stands for current value of a specified dimension and brackets `[...]` are used to reference dimension values.

```
select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
  instructor_id,
  course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt,
  intersects,
  concurrent_courses,
  max_cap_flg
    
from instructor_schedule m
model
  partition by (instructor_id)
  dimension by (course_id, course_start_dt, course_end_dt)
  measures(
    0 as intersects,
    cast(null as varchar(1000)) as concurrent_courses,
    course_id as dummy,
    0 as max_cap_flg
  )
  rules update  sequential order(
    intersects[any, any, any]
      = count(intersects)[
          course_id != cv(course_id),
          course_start_dt <= cv(course_end_dt),
          course_end_dt >= cv(course_start_dt)
        ],
    concurrent_courses[any, any, any]
      = listagg(dummy, ',') within group(order by null)[
          course_id != cv(course_id),
          course_start_dt <= cv(course_end_dt),
          course_end_dt >= cv(course_start_dt)
        ],
    max_cap_flg[any,any,any]
      = case
          when intersects[cv(), cv(), cv()] = max(intersects)[any, any, any]
          then 1
        end
  )
```

| INSTRUCTOR_ID | COURSE_ID | COURSE_START_DT | COURSE_END_DT | INTERSECTS | CONCURRENT_COURSES | MAX_CAP_FLG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | C1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 | 3 | C4,C3,C2 | 1 |
| I1 | C2 | 2021-12-25 | 2022-01-15 | 1 | C1 | *null* |
| I1 | C3 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-05 | 2 | C4,C1 | *null* |
| I1 | C4 | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-26 | 2 | C3,C1 | *null* |
| I1 | C5 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-05 | 0 | *null* | *null* |
| I2 | C1 | 2022-08-20 | 2022-08-22 | 0 | *null* | *null* |
| I2 | C2 | 2022-09-03 | 2022-09-04 | 1 | C4 | *null* |
| I2 | C3 | 2022-09-02 | 2022-09-02 | 1 | C4 | *null* |
| I2 | C4 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-05 | 2 | C3,C2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9Bl4Zmv)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer apply` (in recent versions of Oracle anyway) to get the overlapping courses, and then aggregate those:

```
select i1.instructor_id, i1.course_id, i1.course_start_dt, i1.course_end_dt,
  coalesce(
    listagg(i3.course_id, ',') within group (order by i3.course_id),
    'None') as other_ids,
  count(i3.course_id) as other_count
from instructor_schedule i1
outer apply (
  select i2.course_id
  from instructor_schedule i2
  where i2.instructor_id = i1.instructor_id
  and i2.course_id != i1.course_id
  and not (i2.course_start_dt >= i1.course_end_dt
    or i2.course_end_dt <= i1.course_start_dt)
) i3
group by i1.instructor_id, i1.course_id, i1.course_start_dt, i1.course_end_dt
order by instructor_id, course_id
```

| INSTRUCTOR_ID | COURSE_ID | COURSE_START_DT | COURSE_END_DT | OTHER_IDS | OTHER_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | C1 | 01-JAN-22 | 30-JAN-22 | C2,C3,C4 | 3 |
| I1 | C2 | 25-DEC-21 | 15-JAN-22 | C1 | 1 |
| I1 | C3 | 25-JAN-22 | 05-FEB-22 | C1,C4 | 2 |
| I1 | C4 | 26-JAN-22 | 26-JAN-22 | C1,C3 | 2 |
| I1 | C5 | 01-MAR-22 | 05-MAR-22 | None | 0 |
| I2 | C1 | 20-AUG-22 | 22-AUG-22 | None | 0 |
| I2 | C2 | 03-SEP-22 | 04-SEP-22 | C4 | 1 |
| I2 | C3 | 02-SEP-22 | 02-SEP-22 | C4 | 1 |
| I2 | C4 | 01-SEP-22 | 05-SEP-22 | C2,C3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t6O7p1TU)

This gets a slightly different result to what you've shown, but it looks like instructor I1's C3 and C4 should overlap with each other...

Answer (score 1):

Using just Analytic functions and CASE expressions...

```sql
SELECT INSTRUCTOR_ID, COURSE_ID, COURSE_START_DT, COURSE_END_DT,
       Nvl(OVERLAPING, 'None') "OVERLAPING", CNT
FROM(   SELECT DISTINCT
            i.INSTRUCTOR_ID, i.COURSE_ID, s.OVR, i.COURSE_START_DT, i.COURSE_END_DT,
            LISTAGG(s.COURSE_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By s.COURSE_ID) OVER(Partition By s.INSTRUCTOR_ID, s.OVR) "OVERLAPING",
            COUNT(DISTINCT s.COURSE_ID) OVER(Partition By s.INSTRUCTOR_ID, s.OVR) "CNT"
        FROM
            INSTRUCTOR_SCHEDULE i
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                Select 
                    s1.INSTRUCTOR_ID, s1.COURSE_ID, s1.COURSE_START_DT, s1.COURSE_END_DT,
                    CASE WHEN s1.COURSE_START_DT Between s2.COURSE_START_DT And s2.COURSE_END_DT OR s2.COURSE_START_DT Between s1.COURSE_START_DT And s1.COURSE_END_DT THEN s2.COURSE_ID END "OVR"
                From INSTRUCTOR_SCHEDULE s1
                Inner Join
                    INSTRUCTOR_SCHEDULE s2 ON(s2.INSTRUCTOR_ID = s1.INSTRUCTOR_ID And s2.COURSE_ID !=  s1.COURSE_ID)
                Where 
                    CASE WHEN s1.COURSE_START_DT Between s2.COURSE_START_DT And s2.COURSE_END_DT OR s2.COURSE_START_DT Between s1.COURSE_START_DT And s1.COURSE_END_DT THEN s2.COURSE_ID END Is Not Null
            ) s ON(s.INSTRUCTOR_ID = i.INSTRUCTOR_ID And s.OVR = i.COURSE_ID)
        ORDER BY i.INSTRUCTOR_ID, i.COURSE_ID
    )
/*  R e s u l t :
INSTRUCTOR_ID COURSE_ID COURSE_START_DT COURSE_END_DT OVERLAPING             CNT
------------- --------- --------------- ------------- --------------- ----------
I1            C1        01-JAN-22       30-JAN-22     C2, C3, C4               3 
I1            C2        25-DEC-21       15-JAN-22     C1                       1 
I1            C3        25-JAN-22       05-FEB-22     C1, C4                   2 
I1            C4        26-JAN-22       26-JAN-22     C1, C3                   2 
I1            C5        01-MAR-22       05-MAR-22     None                     0 
I2            C1        20-AUG-22       22-AUG-22     None                     0 
I2            C2        03-SEP-22       04-SEP-22     C4                       1 
I2            C3        02-SEP-22       02-SEP-22     C4                       1 
I2            C4        01-SEP-22       05-SEP-22     C2, C3                   2 
*/
```